# Determine order of building projects in Xcode 5 workspace (with dependencies between static library projects)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode5, static-libraries

I am working with an Xcode workspace that combines one iOS application projects with several iOS static library projects. I've now added a further library *B* project that is dependent on one of its siblings *A* and run into a build error whereby the compiler cannot find one of *A*'s header files when compiling one of *B*'s files.

I assume this has to do with the order in which these projects are built. So I am wondering what determines the order of the different steps. How can I be sure that *A*'s *Copy Files* build phase (which [copies](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/iOSStaticLibraries/Articles/creating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012554-CH2-SW3) the required header file) executes before *B*'s file are compiled. I can see the apparent order of source files for compilation in the target's *Compile Sources* build phase; is there a similar list that determines the "order" of projects inside the workspace. The project navigator view imposes one, but swapping *A* and *B* in that view does not remedy the problem.

Has any one succeeded with this kind of setup (cross-dependency between static library projects in a workspace, all compiled into a single bundle) and what was the required configuration?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the scheme under 'Build' you can drag the targets used into a specific order. If you un-check the 'Parallelize Build' option the targets are built in the specified order. So the later ones can have dependencies to the earlier ones.

Comment: The ordering in the scheme doesn't seem to be followed anymore in Xcode 11. Even with parallelize build unchecked.